# Httpclient redirect handler

Tags: android, redirect, httpclient

I'm trying to call a web server that is using relative URL redirects for some of the calls. This of course isn't working with DefaultHttpClient as it isn't treating it as a relative URL. I've gotten as far as implementing a RedirectHandler in an attempt to catch the redirect and add in the base call but I can't work out how to get the location of the redirect.

With the following method how do I go about finding out where I am being redirected to? I can't find any fields on either response or context that have what I need and I don't know where else to look.

```
public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [HttpClient 4 - how to capture last redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456987/httpclient-4-how-to-capture-last-redirect-url/1457173#1457173)

I would try `getStatusLine()` for start.

Comment: I saw that post. The method there seems to be for finding what redirects have happened after a request completes. When I try that method during a redirect I just get the initial URL that I entered.
getStatusLine() simply gives me 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to read location headers and follow them. This helped me:

```
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Location");

    if (headers != null && headers.length != 0) {
        String newUrl = headers[headers.length - 1].getValue();
        // call again the same downloading method with new URL
        return downloadBitmap(newUrl);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

More in my post - [Follow 302 redirects with AndroidHttpClient](http://blog.kosev.net/2011/01/follow-302-redirects-with.html)