# Handling HttpClient relative redirection

Tags: java, android, apache, redirect, httpclient

I'm working on an Android application with Apache HttpClient, after a post method execution, the response is an error page which contains something like this:

1|#||4|59|pageRedirect||%2fweb%2fError.aspx%3faspxerrorpath%3d%2fWeb%2fdefault.aspx|

I think,(but I'm not sure), the problem could be a relative redirection to /Web/default.aspx where the full URL should be like "www.site.com/Web/default.aspx", is there an easy way to fix it? I'm really goind crazy with this, thank you.

EDIT: the problem is that i don't know how to edit the URL before the redirection because i know what to add before that /Web/default.aspx

however the problem is exactly the same in here: [Httpclient redirect handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131139/httpclient-redirect-handler)
still unsolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this using loopj http client