# Why don't Android web requests automatically follow redirects?

Tags: android, redirect, apache-httpclient-4.x

I had an issue a few weeks ago in a WebView where it wasn't following redirects as a normal browser would. I used the following suggestion given in many SO answers:

```
String newUrl = response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();
```

but it only gave 1 step of redirection, but not more, which it needed to. I got around it by repeatedly listening for redirects and manually going through each step.

Now I'm using the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = MyApp.getHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(con.getString(R.string.platform_url_getBalances));

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", String.valueOf(sessionKey)));
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

String response = null;

// Execute HTTP Post Request. Response body returned as a string
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```

Recently the end-point for the `R.string.platform_url_getBalances` changed but we put in a 302 redirect to a different URL. It works fine in a browser and on the iPad version of the app but for Android I get `org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found`.

I find it very strange that Android is such a pain when it comes to redirecting. Why does it behave like this and is there a reasonable way around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling HttpClient Redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169468/handling-httpclient-redirects) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131139/httpclient-redirect-handler. See also http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2012/04/handle-defaulthttpclient-redirects.html

Comment: That doesn't say why this is the case, and that SO question doesn't have an accepted answer. Also the blog post you linked says "By default DefaultHttpClient will handle redirect automatically", but it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: The first link does "say why this is the case" and does have an accepted answer.

Comment: Didn't notice the first link on the text.

Comment: If you're willing to post this as an answer, I'll accept it, or I'll just delete the question rather than having unanswered questions floating around.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [the answer I linked to in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170468/115145) is for HttpClient 4.1, near as I can tell, and Android's is older.

My guess is that the equivalent process in Android's version of HttpClient would be do:

- Create a subclass of `DefaultRedirectHandler` that overrides `isRedirectRequested()` as appropriate for your app
- Create a subclass of `DefaultHttpClient` and override `createRedirectHandler()` to return an instance of the subclass you created in the previous step
- Use your subclass of `DefaultHttpClient` as a replacement for `DefaultHttpClient` itself wherever you are creating that instance