# Android finding the original url from shortened url

Tags: android

Currently, I am trying to find the original url from a shortened url. I am using the reference from here:

[HttpClient 4 - how to capture last redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456987/httpclient-4-how-to-capture-last-redirect-url/1457173#1457173)

It could work and I am able to get the original url. The purpose if this is to ensure that the shortened url is not not malicious.

But how to I test/ensure that I am actually not accessing the link in order to get the original url?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you want to do is a [HEAD](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead.html) instead of a GET?

Comment: I not sure, but all I want to do is to get the original url without actually accessing the page which defeats the purpose.

Comment: HEAD will just get you the headers and not the page, either or not malicious data can be included in the headers I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I could use HEAD and it still works. But is there any way i could use to test this?